# Adding a new page in an ASP.NET MVC web app in Visual Studio (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

[This is the home page for context](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPnyR.png)

I need to add an "About" page to my ASP.NET MVC web app. I simply don't know what to code/make in order to generate the "About" page when I click on it. I'll be able to add stuff to the page by myself but I don't even know where to start in order to click on the "About" link and have the website go there.

I'm a beginner so please try to keep it simple and let me know if you need anymore context such as the format of my files in the code. Thank you.

Comment: May I ask if you have followed [Microsoft's own _Getting Started_ tutorials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started) in their documentation? If not, why not?

Comment: I'll go ahead and look at that thank you. I'm just getting started with this stuff so I'm not too knowledgeable about where to find information. I've been following Murach's ASP.NET Core MVC (2nd Edition) which covers it but it obviously didn't work out for me. But thank you I will look into the getting started tutorials.

Comment: ASP.NET Core is not ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: I actually was able to figure it out through the Microsoft tutorial. Thank y'all and sorry for any confusion.